# iterate over rows how to increase speed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a very big dataframe (>250.000 rows, 150 columns) and I need to create country and continent code for each rows. I'm using the following code to update the datframe but it is not very efficient. I know that iterrows is not the best option bu I struggle to set up faster iteration code as described in other posts. Could you help me to improve my code?
Thanks

```
for index, row in dfSPSSstudent.iterrows():
    print(row['Country_ID'])
    col = row['Country_ID']
    cn_a2_code =  country_name_to_country_alpha2(col)
    cn_continent = country_alpha2_to_continent_code(cn_a2_code)
    dfSPSSstudent['CN']=cn_a2_code
    print(col, cn_a2_code, cn_continent)
```

Comment: Maybe `dfSPSSstudent["CN"] = dfSPSSstudent["Country_ID"].apply(lambda x: country_alpha2_to_continent_code(country_name_to_country_alpha2(x)))` ?

Comment: remove the print statements - they are _SLOW_. printing 500k rows serves no purpose. if you need print the column afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `apply`:

```
dfSPSSstudent["CN"] = dfSPSSstudent["Country_ID"].apply(lambda x: country_alpha2_to_continent_code(country_name_to_country_alpha2(x)))
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
dfSPSSstudent["CN"] = [country_alpha2_to_continent_code(country_name_to_country_alpha2(x)) for x in dfSPSSstudent["Country_ID"]]
```